How to perform sum(...) over(partition by ... order by ...) in Clickhouse?
I got Clickhouse v. 5.7.30 (24.1.5.).
Is this version got equivalent of windows function:
 sum(...) over(partition by ... order by ...)

I also tried this code:
select  salon_name
        , date
        , runningAccumulate(sumState(revenue_fact_sum), salon_name) as revenue_fact_cumsum
from    revenue_plan_fact_without_cumsum
group by salon_name,
        date
order by salon_name,
        date

But result is strange:

Original data:


see example in docs here: Consider how you can use runningAccumulate to find the cumulative sum of numbers without and with grouping.

Then I need to calculate cumulative sum with:
runningAccumulate(sumState(revenue_fact), salon_name)

I must put in select all column, including column 'revenue_fact'.
In group by I also need add all columns to keep all values of revenue from original table.
select  salon_name
        , date
        , revenue_fact
        , runningAccumulate(sumState(revenue_fact), salon_name) AS revenue_cumulative
from    metrics_for_specializations_with_hour_plan
group by salon_name
        , date
        , revenue_fact
order by salon_name
        , date

If I need add more columns to make "partition by", I need add this columns to select, group by and inside runningAccumulate like this:
select  salon_name
        , specialization_unification
        , date
        , revenue_fact
        , runningAccumulate(sumState(revenue_fact), [salon_name, specialization_unification]) AS revenue_cumulative
from    metrics_for_specializations_with_hour_plan
group by salon_name
        , specialization_unification
        , date
        , revenue_fact
order by salon_name
        , specialization_unification
        , date

It's not obviously for me after reading documentation.

Questions is not clear
Yes ClickHouse 24.1 support window function which you describe above
Look https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/window-functions

Is this an answer as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer ? ( I think it's more a comment...)

@Luuk yes answer is correct
